# What does Dim1 and Dim2 mean in a kmeans plot?

Tags: r, plot, k-means

[image]

I see this type of plot for kmeans. I looked for what dim1 and dim2 represent and what is the interpret of those percents next to them. but I've found nothing clear yet. Could you give an easy explanation of their meaning for kmean clustering?

Image is from : https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/k-means-clustering-visualization-in-r-step-by-step-guide/

Comment: cluster analysis uses a principal component analysis to create clusters. I can image that the image shows the principal component scores of the first two principal components (which explain most of the variation in the data, in this case around 95%)

Comment: What dim1 and dim2 represent thus depends on your data. You can use factor loadings to see which variables score high/low on the factor and through that way come to an interpretation of what they represent

Comment: Possible cross-site duplicate: [What are the x and y axes of clustering plots?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253926/what-are-the-x-and-y-axes-of-clustering-plots).

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a PCA plot. The 73% means that the component of the PC(principal component) accounts for 73% of the total variation. The second PC accounts for 22.9% of the variation. So together they can explain 95.9 % variation in the dataset.